# Flutter image editing with camera prview

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to place/merge/add different images, on camera preview.

When camera preview for taking picture is open, then want a slider at bottom with different thumbnails slider, and what ever is selected will be place/merge/add on the camera preview. and once picture is taken those thumbnails on the image will be captured with camera image.

it is like taking picture and adding different kind of objects like hat, glasses.